# Pandas pivot_table: `margins=True` shows `NaN` with `Period` columns

Tags: python, pandas

The following code reproduces the issue I'm having:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [1, 1, 2, 2],
        "b": [
            pd.Period("2019Q1"),
            pd.Period("2019Q2"),
            pd.Period("2019Q1"),
            pd.Period("2019Q2"),
        ],
        "x": 1.0,
    }
)

df.pivot_table(index="a", columns="b", values="x", margins=True)
```

Output:

```py
b   2019Q1  2019Q2  All
a           
1   1.0     1.0     1.0
2   1.0     1.0     1.0
All NaN     NaN     1.0
```

Why the `NaN` subtotals? I would have expected:

```py
b   2019Q1  2019Q2  All
a           
1   1.0     1.0     1.0
2   1.0     1.0     1.0
All 1.0     1.0     1.0
```

This happens with `Period` columns.

Comment: It seems bug...

Comment: OK, I'll open an issue on GitHub then , thanks

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/28323

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else stumbles across this issue, it is indeed a bug, the relevant GitHub issues are [#28323](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/28323) and [#28337](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/28337)

---

The underlying problem is caused by the `get_indexer` method of a `PeriodIndex`.  Right now, when reindexing, instead of using the actual `PeriodIndex`, the `PeriodIndex`'s `_int64index` is used.  The relevant code [can be found here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/indexes/period.py#L657), and summarized below:

```
if isinstance(target, PeriodIndex):
    target = target.asi8

if tolerance is not None:
    tolerance = self._convert_tolerance(tolerance, target)
return Index.get_indexer(self._int64index, target, method, limit, tolerance)
```

This clearly works fine if re-indexing using another `PeriodIndex`, since the target is also converted to `int`, but results in some wonky behavior if the other index is *not* a `PeriodIndex`, here is a small example of the behavior.

```
>>> i = pd.PeriodIndex([pd.Period("2019Q1", "Q-DEC"), pd.Period("2019Q2", "Q-DEC")])
>>> j = pd.Index([pd.Period("2019Q1", "Q-DEC"), 'All'])
>>> s = pd.Series([1, 2], index=i)
>>> s
2019Q1    1
2019Q2    2
Freq: Q-DEC, dtype: int64
>>> s.reindex(j)
2019Q1   NaN
All      NaN
dtype: float64
>>> s.index._int64index
Int64Index([196, 197], dtype='int64')
>>> s.reindex([196])
196    1
dtype: int64
```

Clearly this is not desired behavior, and the solution is to only use the `_int64index` when reindexing with another `PeriodIndex`, and using the regular `PeriodIndex` otherwise.  I submitted a PR to fix this which hopefully should be included soon.